# Don't trigger a JQuery action on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

There is an element `$dateTimePickerElement` which is triggered on change :
`$dateTimePickerElement.change(function...)`

The problem is that I don't want to trigger the .change() action if i scroll on the element (put the mouse on the element, then scroll).

What can i do to not trigger the element when i scroll with my mouse on it ?

Here is my html:

```
<input type="text" id="dateTimePickerElement" name="dateTimePickerElement"
       required="required" class="form-control" readonly>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$('#dateTimePickerElement').datetimepicker(datePickerOptions).change(dateChanged);
```

Comment: If you have the solution, you should post it as an answer and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

There is an option in datetimepicker : `scrollInput: false`

so i just needed to change my options

```
var datePickerOptions = {
    scrollInput: false
};
```